How to show $NP^{BQP} = QMA$?
I am currently reading the below document authored by @Lieuwe Vinkhuijzen.
In equation 2.1 (page 14 of this), the below equation is mentioned.
$${\Sigma}_1^{BQP} =NP^{BQP}= QMA$$
$NP$, $BQP$, and $QMA$ are formally defined classes. Thus, this proposition needs to be formally argued (for its correction).
My query: I thought of creating a Quantum witness for (promise) QMA complete problem (2-LOCAL HAMILTONIAN problem) using an NP machine having access to BQP oracle (or, $NP^{BQP}$). I need a bit of help on

If this is the correct approach?
If yes, then how can an NP machine create the quantum witness for a complete QMA problem?


I am delighted to hear that people are reading my MSc thesis! Thank you for reaching out with your question.
The confusion arises out of the notation used. Equation 2.1 is a definition of the quantum polynomial hierarchy; it is not a lemma. The symbol $\Sigma_1^{\text{BQP}}$ is ("just") a symbol which means "the first level of the quantum polynomial hierarchy. Equation 2.1,
$$\Sigma_1^{\text{BQP}} = QMA \quad\quad\quad (2.1)$$
means: this symbol $\Sigma_1^{\text{BQP}}$ is defined to be the complexity class $\textbf{QMA}$. When I introduced this hierarchy, I adapte the notation from $\Sigma_1^{P}$. The idea is that the $P$ in $\Sigma_1^P$ refers to the underlying computational model, so, I just change the underlying computational model from $P$ to $BQP$. (Perhaps it would have been better to write $\Sigma_1^{BQP}:=QMA$)
The definition is inductive, so $\Sigma_{i+1}^{BQP}$ is defined in terms of $\Sigma_i^{BQP}$:
$$\Sigma_{i+1}^{\text{BQP}}:=QMA^{\Sigma_i^{\text{BQP}}} $$
That is, the complexity class $\Sigma_{i+1}^{\text{BQP}}$, the next level of the hierarchy, is obtained "simply" by giving a $QMA$ machine oracle access to the previous layer in the hierarchy. This is similar to how the class $\Sigma_{i+1}^{P}$ is obtained by giving an $NP$ oracle access to (any language in) the previous layer of the hierarchy.
Similarly, the notation
$$\Delta_1^{\text{BQP}}=\text{BQP} $$
defines $\Delta_1^{\text{BQP}}$ as equal to $BQP$.

As an aside, the question of whether $NP^{BQP}\overset{?}{=}QMA$ is an interesting one. A similar question is asked by $QCMA\overset ?= QMA$, which asks essentially whether the ground state of every Hamiltonian can be prepared in polynomial time, see e.g. [1] or [2]
[1] P. Wocjan, D. Janzing, Two QCMA-complete problems. 2003.
[2] Scott Aaronson, Quantum Computing Since Democritus, 2013.
